# Laravel Blade - Bucle foreach que llame a una función javascript

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6

estoy usando Laravel con las plantillas blade y lo que intento hacer es un bucle foreach que llame a una función javascript que tengo hecha.

La **función JS** es esta

```
    <script>
        function constructLiElement(form_element)
        {
            var li = '<li class="action-element ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="txtType">'+
                ' <div data-id={{$form_element["id"]}} data-uuid={{$form_element["uuid"]}} class="element {{$form_element["element_type"]}}"> '+
                '</div>';

            return li;
        }
    </script>
```

Y el bucle foreach que intento hacer es este

```
      @foreach($forms_elements as $form_element)
          //aqui debo llamar la función JS pasando form_element como parametro
      @endforeach
```

En este bucle es donde no veo como llamar a la función JS anterior, pasando como parámetro **form_element**

Comment: ¿Porqué hacerlo así? Puedes construir esa estructura con Laravel, sin necesidad de JS. No tiene sentido práctico mezclar lenguaje del *frontend* con lenguaje del *backend*. Yo usaría PHP directamente para realizar ese render específico. Saludos

Comment: Ese fichero es un "form builder" y al cargar la página es cierto que hago un bucle desde blade si tengo elementos que me devuelve el controlador, sino los construyo desde jquery, la idea es tenerlo en una función JS porque sinó (es como lo tengo ahora) tengo el bucle foreach de blade y luego una función en JS que hacen lo mismo